# How to pass data to ViewController in new storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I use this code for go to new story board and pass variable X to a viewController in new storyboard

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerCall")
homeViewController.myVar = "x"
self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I get this error:

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'myVar'

Comment: Error it self said that in UIViewController you need to create myVar name variable first, this is basic things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this line:

```
let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerCall")
```

You are saying "Instantiate a view controller from the storyboard, and infer its type to be a `UIViewController`". However, what you need to do is specifying it as `ViewControllerCall`.

You can do this by type casting - adding `as? ViewControllerCall`. (Or `as! ViewControllerCall`, if you don't want to use the `if let` clause).

Your code should look like this:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let homeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerCall") as? ViewControllerCall {
    homeViewController.myVar = "x"
    self.present(homeViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Or

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerCall") as! ViewControllerCall
homeViewController.myVar = "x"
self.present(homeViewController, animated: true)
```

Note that by using `as!` in the second way I've presented, it will crash your app if the view controller with identifier `ViewControllerCall` is not of type ViewControllerCall.

Comment: thank you, but i get error again : Value of type 'ViewControllerIndex' has no member 'myVar'

Comment: @salarimameri what is the class name for your view controller with the identifier `ViewControllerCall`?

Comment: class name : class ViewControllerCall: UIViewController, QBRTCClientDelegate {. And storyboard id : ViewControllerCall

Answer (score 0):

You have to change second line code only.
1. Go to your **Main** storyboard and check the class for ViewController for which you want to pass variable and set storyboard identifier same as class name.
2. Now if your class name is "**ViewControllerCall**" then change your line code as below:

```
let homeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerCall") as! ViewControllerCall
```